# Create tasks inside class with critical section

Tags: java, concurrency, race-condition

I want to create a `List` of `Runnable`s inside a class, so they could later be executed with a simple thread pool, I want to check I dont have any race condition issues.
This is the class.
Note that each call to `createTasks` create a new lock, the locks should not be shared across multiple calls to `createTasks`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestConcurrency {

    private final List<Boolean> locks;

    public TestConcurrency() {
        locks = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void happenOnce() {
        System.out.println("This line should be printed ONCE");
    }

    public List<Runnable> createTasks() {
        locks.add(false);
        final int lastIndex = locks.size() - 1;
        List<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            tasks.add(() -> {
                Boolean currentLock = locks.get(lastIndex);
                System.out.println("This line should be printed for every thread, " +
                        "currentLock value before re-access" + currentLock);
                synchronized (currentLock) {
                    // This is a little risky move, we already hold a value
                    // of `currentLock` that were accessed OUTSIDE the
                    // critical section, so multiple threads can hold the
                    // wrong value, so we access it again after acquiring the lock
                    currentLock = locks.get(lastIndex);

                    if (!currentLock) {
                        happenOnce();
                        synchronized (locks) {
                            locks.remove(lastIndex);
                            locks.add(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return tasks;
    }
}
```

After defining the above class, I use it in the following way:

```
public class MyProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestConcurrency tc = new TestConcurrency();

        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (Runnable task: tc.createTasks()) {
            Future<?> z = executor.submit(task);
        }
    }
}
```

Does this code seems ok to you? The method `happenOnce` should happen only once, of course

Comment: FYI: `locks.add(false)` is shorthand for `locks.add(Boolean.valueOf(false))`, and `valueOf(false)` always returns a reference to the same instance, `Boolean.FALSE`. In other words, each call to `createTasks` does _not_ create a new lock. It uses the same lock as every other call.

Comment: I assume this is not the case of Integer

Comment: When you use `false` where a `Boolean` is expected and it calls `Boolean.valueOf(false)`, that's called [_autoboxing_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). Similarly, autoboxing for `Integer` calls `Integer.valueOf(...)`. [Documentation for `Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) promises that for any given value in the range [-128..127], it will always return the same unique object, just like how `Boolean.valueOf(false)` and `Boolean.valueOf(true)` each return a certain unique object.

Comment: Any other advice on how to make this code better?

Comment: This code is horribly broken, in multiple ways, even beyond the incorrect synchronization. For example, think about what `locks.remove(lastIndex); locks.add(true);` is intended to do and what it actually does. But in what scope is `happenOnce();` supposed to happen once? Your code seems to try to execute it one hundred times instead of once, as otherwise you wouldn’t need 100 different locks. This is self-contradicting. So what is the actual goal?